# Author_meta ONLY if it exists

Tags: post-meta

I'd like to ONLY show the authors website link if it exists, but I can't work out the exact syntax for it.

I have this

```
        if ( get_the_author_meta('user_url') ) : // If a user has filled out their decscription show a bio on their entries

         echo  the_author_meta('user_url');

        endif;
```

But I need to wrap it in a link and give that link a class, like this

```
<a class="meta-website" href="<?php the_author_meta('user_url') ?>">Author's Website</a>
```

The problem is when I add another 'echo' before the_author_meta one it just breaks the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing $user_ID global variable to function as following. it is working for me.

```
<?php 
  global $user_ID;
  if ( get_the_author_meta('user_url',$user_ID) ) : // If a user has filled out their decscription show a bio on their entries 
?>
  <a class="meta-website" href="<?php the_author_meta('user_url',$user_ID); ?>">Author's Website</a>    
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: EDIT - I'm an idiot, it does work, hehe. :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is answered, but for future reference, `echo  the_author_meta('user_url');` Won't work because `the_author_meta()` outputs the value, so you're trying to echo echo essentially.

You can echo `get_the_author_meta()` if you're going to keep it with the `<?php ?>`